# HTTP method parameter becomes null when there are too many child entities to be deserialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
[HttpPost] public JsonResult Edit(Employee e) { }
```

I post a request via jQuery as json data to this Edit method; data looks like this:

```
{"OperationType": "Edit", "IdEmployee": 123, "FamilyMembers": [{Id:1, "Name" : "Child1"}, // n entities]}
```

I have around 32 entities in the "FamilyMembers". When I push this with jQuery, the employee entity on the receiving method is null. However, if I push only 24 entities in the "FamilyMember", the parameter is no longer null.

What could be causing such issue ?

Comment: You're likely hitting the maximum size of a request (look at the error logs). There are a number of questions about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's hard to help without accurate information to reproduce the issue. Take a look at your browser's network requests to see exactly what you're sending in each instance, see if there is a typo somewhere. The entire `e` variable would be null or you'd get a 4xx status code if the request content was too large.